# How do we pass parameters to an Aura.Action?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am trying to avoid using Component events by having a simple attribute that I'll put on a child component. To make it simple, I created an app that handles the call. Some code follows.

## methodDemoApp

---

```
<aura:application >
    <c:methodDemoChild onUpdate="{!c.doUpdate}" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    doUpdate: function(component, event, helper) {
        alert("doUpdate called");
    }
})
```

---

## methodDemoChild

---

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="onUpdate" type="Aura.Action" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("v.onUpdate");
        action.setParam('testValue', 5);
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

---

In this code, the alert appears. However, in the doUpdate method, the event parameter (the second parameter) is "undefined". This means that I have no way to get the event's source, which is a problem, since the goal is to ultimately be able to identify which child component (in a list of items) that fired the event, and even more importantly, the parameters I specified using setParam/setParams.

The goal is to avoid writing a custom event just for the purpose of communicating between the parent and child. If I had a way to pass the parameters to the parent method, there'd be no need for a custom event, which would reduce the clutter in my code.

*What is the minimum modification I would need to construct an event and pass that data to the parent component?*

Comment: I am still researching it but the 3 ways i can think of is 1,setting a pass by reference child attribute and read it in parent when the event is fired, 2.use window object and set a parameter, 3.use local storage to set a parameter. I am still trying if we can pass a parameter through Aura:Action. No luck till now though :(

Comment: This would be indeed an excellent solution to reduce our org code and components!

Comment: @sfdcfox
Were you able to send param using Aura Actions ? 
or you had to go with events to pass param to parent component?

Thanks.

Comment: @Sriram I went with the event, instead. It wasn't worth the effort to go through trying to make aura:method work when there's already a documented solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Winter 2018 in lightning component [bookshelf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_aura_action.htm) salesforce had added the below documentation to not use aura:action to pass an action from parent to child.

Seems events is the way to go!

> Although Aura.Action works for passing an action handler to a child
>   component, we recommend registering an event in the child component
>   and firing the event in the child’s controller instead. Then, handle
>   the event in the parent component. The event approach requires a few
>   extra steps in creating or choosing an event and firing it but events
>   are the standard way to communicate between components.
>
> Aura.Action shouldn’t be used for other use cases. Here are some known
>   limitations of Aura.Action.
>
> Don’t use cmp.set() in JavaScript code to reset an attribute of
>   type="Aura.Action" after it’s previously been set. Doing so generates
>   an error. 1 Unable to set value for key 'c.passedAction'. Value
>   provider does not implement 'set(key, value)'. : false Don’t use
>   $A.enqueueAction() in the child component to enqueue the action passed
>   to the Aura.Action attribute. Aura.Action is like a haunted house.
>   Passing an action to a child component is like going into the haunted
>   house during the day. All is well, even though passing an action
>   between components feels a little wrong. Don’t be that kid who ignores
>   all warnings and goes into the haunted house at night. That story
>   doesn’t end well.